# Name of classmap

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

I am trying to get the values as objects of attributes and elements out from a XML response using a php built-in soap client. I am trying to solve this with classmap, but still no result...

SOAPCLIENT:

```
$client = new MySoapClient(null, array('trace' => 1, 'login' => $myusername, 'password' => $mypassword, 'location' => $location, 'uri' => "http://www.myuri.com/", 'soapVersion' => SOAP_1_1, 'use' => SOAP_LITERAL, 'style' => 'SOAP_DOCUMENT', 'soapaction' => $Operation, 'classmap' => array('AttributPrice' => 'MyAttributPriceClass')));

$ans = $client->__call("$Operation", array("_" => $MyParameter, "parameters2" => $MyVar), array('soapaction' => "$Operation", 'uri' => "http://www.myuri.com/$FileName"));
```

XML response looks like this:
ValueOfElement

I need the value of the attributes key, price, netprice and revenue AND the value of the element.

I tried to use classmap, but all I am getting is objects with the value of the element (I am missing the value of the attributes). How actually classmap works? The WSDL file is quite complex and long. The actually question is: What is the name of the classmap? Where can I find it in the WSDL file (The client is using many WSDL & XSD files)? How can I make myself sure that I am using the correct classmap name? Btw, I dont want to use parsing or similar.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Note `classmap` only works in WSDL mode.

After instantiating client, execute __getTypes(), like so:

```
$client = new MySoapClient(...);
$types = $client->__getTypes();
```

It will show you a list of types you can use to map to your class.

If indeed, the type is `AttributPrice`, then you can:

```
$classMap = array('AttributPrice' => 'MyAttributPriceClass');
$client = new MySoapClient($wsdl, array('classmap' => $classMap));
```